# how to add the same JLabel to multiply JLabels in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, label, jlabel

i writing gui for my program in java, and i want to show some jlabel in multiply jlabels. im using gridlayout.

parts of code:

```
protected JLabel myLbl = new JLabel("1");
protected JLabel first = new JLabel("2");
protected JLabel second = new Jlabel("3");
```

in the constructor:

```
this.first.add(myLbl);
this.second.add(myLbl);
```

I saw a few questions on the subject, here in StackOverFlow, but I could not find a solution there without creating a duplicate JLabels.. And without creating another layout.

Is there a way to do this without creating a new layout or duplicate JLabels?

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect as a result of that? Do you want to concat the text of the `JLabel` objects?

Comment: I expect to see the text of myLbl inside first and second labels next to their text.. 
I need another JLabel because I want the font of text 1 to be smaller than the font of the JLabels first and second

Comment: always try to post a [MCVE]